# Android 13 - enable accessibility service for APK which installed not from Google Play

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-13

On the [beta version of Android 13](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/get) user can't enable Accessibility from the Settings app. When the user try to do it there is an error:

> Restricted Setting
> For your security, this setting is currently unavailable.

How can I enable accessibility on Android 13?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

1. Go to app info.
2. Tap on 3 dots.
3. Choose "allow restricted settings".
4. You'll asked for your lock code.

Now you can enable accessibility.

Comment: A side note: on Android 14 this option isn’t available. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75875832/accessibilty-service-in-android-14-out-of-google-play

Comment: An update to the above: they fixed the bug, so it also in Android 14

Comment: I don't have 3 dots on some Android 12, what now? (also Accessibility Service is "grayed-out", can't be enabled when installing from APK)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to zvi's answer,

You'll have to go through settings - apps - and then open the specific app from there. If you open app info from recent or through any other third party app, you won't find the option to allow restricted settings.

Comment: Thanks. Not at all obvious. Key point is that you must find the app in the alphabetical list of apps and not through the recents lists under Settings > apps.

This works on Omnirom 13.

Answer (score 1):

The three dots are not available on my Redmagic 8, a13.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34391969)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Samsung **S21 FE** (Brazil Pt-Br) and not saw this restriction. I'm able to sideload and enable accessibility service in any app normally.

Probaly this can be related with this question:

- [Android 13 Restricted Settings(Accessibility) API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73554847/android-13-restricted-settingsaccessibility-api)

Answer (score 0):

On Realme Android 13 you can find the setting under:
Settings > Additional settings > Accessibility
and there under More you should have the app which needs accessibility. Click on it and then hit the button to turn on accessibility for this app.