# Local install of APK in Android 13

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions, selinux, android-13

**Goal:** Have an app that can update itself on a custom/rooted ROM in Android 13 by saving the APK locally, then having an app install it without user [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72217216/android-13-enable-accessibility-service-for-apk-which-installed-not-from-googl).

**Solution:** Use an [intention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission) as described in the second answer here.

**What no longer works:**

Originally this was a question because after a lot of time I only found out-of-date answers. Android keeps on increasing security and deprecating old APIs. Here's a list of rabbit holes to avoid.

1. Install with exec(), `su`, and `pm install`
2. Granting the app `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` and similar permissions
3. Forcing ROM into permissive mode at compile to avoid SELINUX blocking access

*Approach 1* fails because you will get `Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied`. First you need to move the APK into a [tmp dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540334/install-apk-using-root-handling-new-limitations-of-data-local-tmp-folder). However when you try to run `su` you get the exception. You need to be `su` for `pm install -r -d foobar.apk` to [work](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217430/local-equivalent-to-adb-install). This used to be the most common way that people installed a new apk. Even if there were no issues with it I would recommend using the answer above as its less of a hack.

*Approach 2* seems to be just out of date and Android has moved on.

*Approach 3* is an attempt to get around the `su` issue. It's unclear if SELINUX is really what was causing the exception to be thrown and maybe someone can clarify what's going on. SELINUX is what was blamed and a lot of people spent a lot of time trying to create custom rules.

To get something that worked I attempted to [force](https://github.com/Zackptg5/Kernel-Sepolicy-Patcher/issues/1) the [device](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/b90vyn/how_can_you_disable_selinux_when_building_oreo/) into [permissive mode](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/selinux/implement#steps). Using compile time flags doesn't work `BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.selinux=permissive` and Google needs to update the instructions. I could write more here, but it's a black hole. Looking at [logs](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/selinux/validate) there was no indication SELINUX was blocking 'su'.

Comment: For anyone else OP appears to found a [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440665/295004).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for pointing people in the right direction. Going to update the question now with the new info and document what no longer works.