# Accessibilty service in Android 14 (out of Google Play)

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-14

Allow accessibility service for APK that is out of Google Play:

- In Android 13 Google added "restricted settings" where the user can check and then he can allow accessibility service. See here: https://support.google.com/android/answer/12623953
- In Android 14 there is no such option as "restricted settings".

How can the user approve accessibility service?

Comment: We opened a bug for Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275258164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy news: Google fixed the bug and on the latest beta version of Android 14 it's ok.

See here:
[issuetracker.google.com/issues/275258164](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275258164)